Spoofing email address in 2024? How do they do it?
So I think I know the basics of SPF, DKIM, DMARC, and I understand why we can't spoof email addresses like it's 1998. But how does phishing like this, still exist in 2024:

It's extremely rare that I see real sender addresses like this, because obviously, this just won't work with SPF/DKIM/DMARC. But the sender from actual mail headers read:
From: "service@paypal.com" service@paypal.com
How do they do it? How do they circumvent SPF/DKIM/DMARC? I mean, I assume that PayPal will have their DNS records cemented thoroughly, right?
They even lose 7.5 spam score points (ESF):

-7.5 USER_IN_DEF_DKIM_WL     From: address is in the default DKIM
welcome-list

It is my spam filtering (ESF) failing here, or are they doing something seriously nifty. It's always easy to spot these as phishing, because the "To:" header is always some bogus (usually microsoft.com) address. But still. Got another one today from a microsoft.com address. Headers show a long list of (microsoft) servers where the message passed. Still interested how they manage this. Wouldn't be surprised if a loophole with Microsoft is involved, their servers/domains always seem to be involved.
ESF is not being triggered, it even has a check for "Claims to be from paypal, sent to Microsoft365 domain - likely fraud if you don't use MSFT365!". I don't, I don't own any microsoft.com (email) accounts. It probably should have, but how did this message escape SPF in the first place?
Full message headers below. Changed a few bits for privacy reasons:

mydomain.com: was my domain name
myname: was my name
myserverdomain: was my server domain name

Return-path: <SRS0=eUqRWE=TG=paypal.com=service@mydomain.com>
Envelope-to: myname@mydomain.com
Delivery-date: Fri, 13 Dec 2024 16:40:51 +0100
Received: from mail-dm6nam11lp2177.outbound.protection.outlook.com ([104.47.57.177] helo=NAM11-DM6-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com)
    by server.myserverdomain with esmtps  (TLS1.2) tls TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    (Exim 4.94)
    (envelope-from <service@paypal.com>)
    id 1tM7mb-0007Xh-J5
    for myname@mydomain.com; Fri, 13 Dec 2024 16:40:51 +0100
Received: from CH0P221MB0520.NAMP221.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:10b6:610:10d::19)
 by CH3P221MB1301.NAMP221.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:10b6:610:1b3::8) with
 Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.8251.15; Fri, 13 Dec
 2024 15:36:25 +0000
Received: from PH8P221MB1064.NAMP221.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:10b6:510:1c8::5)
 by CH0P221MB0520.NAMP221.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:10b6:610:10d::19) with
 Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.8251.16; Fri, 13 Dec
 2024 15:35:32 +0000
Received: from PH8P221MB1064.NAMP221.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
 ([fe80::cbb9:aac0:166a:39f]) by PH8P221MB1064.NAMP221.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
 ([fe80::cbb9:aac0:166a:39f%7]) with mapi id 15.20.8230.010; Fri, 13 Dec 2024
 15:35:32 +0000
Received: from SJ0PR13CA0051.namprd13.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:a03:2c2::26)
 by SA1P221MB1360.NAMP221.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:10b6:806:3e2::21) with
 Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.8230.18; Fri, 13 Dec
 2024 14:58:44 +0000
Received: from CO1PEPF000042A9.namprd03.prod.outlook.com
 (2603:10b6:a03:2c2:cafe::f5) by SJ0PR13CA0051.outlook.office365.com
 (2603:10b6:a03:2c2::26) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_3,
 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.8272.5 via Frontend Transport; Fri,
 13 Dec 2024 14:58:44 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=softfail (sender IP is 104.47.26.41)
 smtp.mailfrom=paypal.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified)
 header.d=paypal.com;dmarc=pass action=none header.from=paypal.com;
Received-SPF: SoftFail (protection.outlook.com: domain of transitioning
 paypal.com discourages use of 104.47.26.41 as permitted sender)
Received: from APC01-PSA-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com (104.47.26.41) by
 CO1PEPF000042A9.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.167.243.38) with Microsoft
 SMTP Server (version=TLS1_3, cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.8251.15
 via Frontend Transport; Fri, 13 Dec 2024 14:58:43 +0000
Received: from PSAPR01MB3944.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com
 (2603:1096:301:47::11) by SG2PR01MB4097.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com
 (2603:1096:4:1c0::11) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.8230.19; Fri, 13 Dec
 2024 14:55:56 +0000
Received: from PSAPR01MB3944.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com
 ([fe80::c921:b2d5:8914:3896]) by PSAPR01MB3944.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com
 ([fe80::c921:b2d5:8914:3896%4]) with mapi id 15.20.8251.015; Fri, 13 Dec 2024
 14:55:56 +0000
Received: from PUZP153CA0015.APCP153.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:1096:301:c2::13)
 by OSNPR01MB7748.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com (2603:1096:604:317::13) with
 Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.8230.19; Fri, 13 Dec
 2024 14:54:20 +0000
Received: from HK2PEPF00006FB3.apcprd02.prod.outlook.com
 (2603:1096:301:c2:cafe::1d) by PUZP153CA0015.outlook.office365.com
 (2603:1096:301:c2::13) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_3,
 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.8272.4 via Frontend Transport; Fri,
 13 Dec 2024 14:54:20 +0000
Authentication-Results-Original: spf=pass (sender IP is 66.211.170.94)
 smtp.mailfrom=paypal.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified)
 header.d=paypal.com;dmarc=pass action=none header.from=paypal.com;
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of paypal.com designates
 66.211.170.94 as permitted sender) receiver=protection.outlook.com;
 client-ip=66.211.170.94; helo=mx10.phx.paypal.com; pr=C
Received: from mx10.phx.paypal.com (66.211.170.94) by
 HK2PEPF00006FB3.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.167.8.9) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id
 15.20.8251.15 via Frontend Transport; Fri, 13 Dec 2024 14:54:19 +0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; d=paypal.com; s=pp-dkim1; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    q=dns/txt; i=@paypal.com; t=1734101657;
    h=From:From:Subject:Date:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type;
    bh=84fe6HBaKiwNYOP82k4My1CU200+iXPO4AlFa2gb93g=;
    b=zrJRPbjvJuQv3US3SrK88TKiq1RdsDLlAPxsO2QsTplH8pM4cXD5InoKI+LYOYFp
    t91xZsA3PeqhIAit802Fbvnwb7ekShaqEv4M6SRMij4HgBjtmL1EmjzGauHOAd7k
    oh8R4LByfi6ZjjxH0Tp/HtFkBrTtZfRgS5G+wWAPk8m5PpVUu1JcdzDVSjlzEeMy
    jGDGY/mbFvjUW7xd+R3O+njH645qXm9iaTT/hZ0h4k5kG/vG5N0IUtWU8dmDIDmV
    gU/zkffE+Uwe7Ft5eCnlvl88wtgQ+kBA3SfrANWCYb2YUwZ2riItA+1R3JIGCAwT
    W4vsX2SEE0QWwD2jMl6LrA==;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Date: Fri, 13 Dec 2024 06:54:17 -0800
Message-ID: <99.FF.22381.99A4C576@ccg01mail10>
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "service@paypal.com" <service@paypal.com>
To: orderstatus10@oplacrm.onmicrosoft.com
Subject: You've got a money request
X-MaxCode-Template: PPC001017
X-PP-Priority: 0-none-false
PP-Correlation-Id: f251106d671cd
X-PP-Email-transmission-Id: 20b5e63f-b962-11ef-b72b-8598d087db10
X-PP-REQUESTED-TIME: 1734101653276
X-Email-Type-Id: PPC001017
AMQ-Delivery-Message-Id: nullval
X-XPT-XSL-Name: nullval
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 1
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic:
    HK2PEPF00006FB3:EE_|OSNPR01MB7748:EE_|SG2PR01MB4097:EE_|CO1PEPF000042A9:EE_|SA1P221MB1360:EE_|CH0P221MB0520:EE_|CH3P221MB1301:EE_
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: a248d5bf-27dc-4557-8704-08dd1b86a384
X-Moderation-Data: 12/13/2024 2:55:54 PM
X-LD-Processed: 722a6975-ecfd-47c3-8d05-f280bdb2cfd8,ExtAddr
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: DR, OOF, AutoReply
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: SG2PR01MB4097
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 624f3c32-f22b-428d-b817-8e4e6859e628:0
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStripped: CO1PEPF000042A9.namprd03.prod.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersPromoted: CO1PEPF000042A9.namprd03.prod.outlook.com
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id-Prvs:
 14bebb39-181f-4c10-194b-08dd1b86065c
X-Moderation-Data: 12/13/2024 3:35:30 PM
X-LD-Processed: 624f3c32-f22b-428d-b817-8e4e6859e628,ExtAddr,ExtAddr
X-OriginatorOrg: dokandar.shop
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: a248d5bf-27dc-4557-8704-08dd1b86a384
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 624f3c32-f22b-428d-b817-8e4e6859e628
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthSource: CO1PEPF000042A9.namprd03.prod.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 13 Dec 2024 15:35:32.1868
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: CH3P221MB1301
Forward-Confirmed-ReverseDNS: Reverse and forward lookup success on 104.47.57.177, -10 Spam score
BlacklistCheck: Blacklisted address, +50 Spam score
SPFCheck: Soft Fail, 30 Spam score
X-DKIM: signer='paypal.com' status='pass' reason=''
DKIMCheck: Server passes DKIM test, -20 Spam score
X-DKIM: signer='@paypal.com' status='pass' reason=''
X-Spam-Score: -8.3 (--------)
X-Spam-Report: Spam detection software, running on the system "server.myserverdomain",
 has NOT identified this incoming email as spam.  The original
 message has been attached to this so you can view it or label
 similar future email.  If you have any questions, see
 the administrator of that system for details.
 
 Content preview:  You've got a money request orderstatus10@oplacrm. onmicrosoft.
    com, here are the request details. Hello, orderstatus10@oplacrm. onmicrosoft.
    com CN Accounting & Business Services, LLC sent you a money request 
 
 Content analysis details:   (-8.3 points, 5.0 required)
 
  pts rule name              description
 ---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
 -1.9 BAYES_00               BODY: Bayes spam probability is 0 to 1%
                             [score: 0.0000]
 -0.0 RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2      RBL: Average reputation (+2)
                             [104.47.57.177 listed in wl.mailspike.net]
  0.0 RCVD_IN_ZEN_BLOCKED_OPENDNS RBL: ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query
                              to zen.spamhaus.org was blocked due to
                             usage of an open resolver. See
                             https://www.spamhaus.org/returnc/pub/
                             [104.47.57.177 listed in zen.spamhaus.org]
 -0.0 RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE     RBL: Sender listed at https://www.dnswl.org/,
                              no trust
                             [104.47.57.177 listed in list.dnswl.org]
  0.0 RCVD_IN_VALIDITY_SAFE_BLOCKED RBL: ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The
                             query to Validity was blocked.  See
                             https://knowledge.validity.com/hc/en-us/articles/20961730681243
                              for more information.
                          [104.47.57.177 listed in sa-trusted.bondedsender.org]
  0.0 RCVD_IN_VALIDITY_RPBL_BLOCKED RBL: ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The
                             query to Validity was blocked.  See
                             https://knowledge.validity.com/hc/en-us/articles/20961730681243
                              for more information.
                             [104.47.57.177 listed in bl.score.senderscore.com]
 -0.0 SPF_HELO_PASS          SPF: HELO matches SPF record
  0.7 SPF_SOFTFAIL           SPF: sender does not match SPF record (softfail)
 -7.5 USER_IN_DEF_DKIM_WL    From: address is in the default DKIM
                             welcome-list
  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
  0.1 MIME_HTML_ONLY         BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
 -0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from
                             author's domain
 -0.1 DKIM_VALID             Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
  0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
                             valid
 -0.1 DKIM_VALID_EF          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from
                             envelope-from domain
  0.0 POSSIBLE_PAYPAL_PHISH_03 Claims to be from paypal, sent to
                             Microsoft365 domain - likely fraud if you
                             don't use MSFT365!
  1.0 FORGED_SPF_HELO        No description available.
  0.0 POSSIBLE_PAYPAL_PHISH_04 Claims to be from paypal, greets email
                             address rather than full name
  0.0 T_REMOTE_IMAGE         Message contains an external image
 -0.5 DKIMWL_WL_HIGH         DKIMwl.org - High trust sender
SpamTally: Final spam score: -52


Unless you give us full headers there's no way we can answer

You're right, I added the full headers. Had it already planned, but it escaped my mind.

Even better - they spoofed a Paypal IP address, and convinced Microsoft that they are a "high trust sender". /s

You have configured lookups to RBLs, but are not querying them in line with their operators guidelines and thus do not get the benefit. Fix that.

Seems like a bogus money request. But the email did come from paypal servers. SPF, DKIM, and DMARC are all good when it hits the first MS server.

This looks to me like it is a problem with the "USER_IN_DEF_DKIM_WL" feature. The email is sent by a high trust host, but the SPF is NOT valid. So it's an email from a high trust sender, validly DKIM signed, but not actually from paypal - frankly the USER_IN_DEF_DKIM_WL seems way way too high of a weight. I'm going to drop it down to 1.5 immediately on my own server. I got the same email spam but serverfault is blocking me from putting in the email headers.

With a score of 1.5 this message would have come through anyhow. I don't think that's the real problem. Therefore my question: why is the basic SPF system of the mailserver itself (Exim) not getting triggered by this message? Spamfilters like Spamassassin do their thing afterwards, right?
